# Linux 3.13 Kernel Module set procfile_read end of file condition

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, posix

I am writing a Kernel Module for Linux 3.13 where the procfile_read function prototype is defined as:

```
static ssize_t procfile_read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t * data)
```

This is different from every resource I can find online, such as http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html, where the function prototype was different for Linux 2.x

How can I set the end of file condition in the new procfile_read function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I needed to do. (Didn't exactly need to set the EOF indicator, but just needed to increase the position so cat did not endlessly read from my procfile.)

The loff_t *data argument should actually be named offset or position. (I think this fits it's purpose better, data is ambigious) I looked at this page for an example definition: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/seq_file.c#L165

```
156 /**
157  *      seq_read -      ->read() method for sequential files.
158  *      @file: the file to read from
159  *      @buf: the buffer to read to
160  *      @size: the maximum number of bytes to read
161  *      @ppos: the current position in the file
162  *
163  *      Ready-made ->f_op->read()
164  */
165 ssize_t seq_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *ppos)
```

Anyways working code example: 
You need to increase the value of *data before you return (To let the user program know it's new position). Then you can check if it's >0 during the next call.

```
static ssize_t proc_read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t * data){

    if((int)*data>0){
        return 0;
    }

    char * ret_str;
    ret_str= "Test\n";

    *data += 6;
    memcpy(buffer, ret_str, 6);
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: `seq_read` is an other to implement `/proc` filesystem and this is a suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the interface you are now using is obsolete, [this](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) may help you.

I also have a small example of `/proc` filesystem:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

static int proc_read (char *page, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data);


static int proc_read (char *page, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data) {
    int reval = 0;

    reval = sprintf(page, "Hello world\n");
    *eof = 1;

    return reval;
}

static int __init proc_init(void) {
    struct proc_dir_entry * proc_entry;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello Proc\n");

    proc_entry = create_proc_read_entry("test_proc", 0, NULL, proc_read, NULL);


    return 0;
}


static void __exit proc_exit(void) {
    remove_proc_entry("test_proc", NULL);

}

module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Douglas");
```

you can execute `cat /proc/test_proc` to test this program.

Comment: Which Kernel Version is this for? The proc_read function prototype is different. In Linux 3.13 it doesn't have int *eof anymore. So I'm not sure how to set it.

Comment: I work on kernel 3.2.65, The program i have showed works very well. http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/ may help you.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your answer. I figured out how to do what I needed with Linux 3.13 and am posting my solution in the answer section.